# Web Flow problems from GET Jsp to a POST JSP (Form) - Spring MVC Annotated

Tags: java

i have a JSP with hyperlink

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Product Name : </td>
    <td>${product.name}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Description:</td>
    <td>${product.description}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Price:</td>
    <td>${product.price}</td>
</tr>   
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>        
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="../shopbasket/populateBasket?code=${product.productCode}&name=${categoryName}">Add to shopping basket</a>                              
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>                                                    
<tr>
    <td>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="<c:url value="../index.html"/>">Return to Home Page</a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Logout</a>
                (<security:authentication property="principal.username" />)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the controller

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("basket")
public class ShopBasketController {

```
private BasketManager basketManager;
private CustomerManager customerManager;
private CategoryManager categoryManager;

@Autowired 
public ShopBasketController(BasketManager basketManager, CustomerManager customerManager, CategoryManager categoryManager) {
    this.basketManager = basketManager;
    this.customerManager = customerManager;
    this.categoryManager = categoryManager;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/basketItems", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String removeProduct(@ModelAttribute("basket") Basket basket, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {        
    Basket newBasket = ShoppingBasketUtils.removeFromBasket(basket, basketManager);
    basketManager.update(newBasket);
    model.addAttribute("basket",newBasket);
    model.addAttribute("customer", "Sonx"+" Nkuks");
    model.addAttribute("totalItems", basketManager.getTotalNumberOfItems(basket));
    model.addAttribute("totalPrice", ShoppingBasketUtils.currencyFormat(basketManager.getTotalProductPrice(basket)));       
    return "basketItems";   
}   

@RequestMapping("/populateBasket")
public String populateBasket(@RequestParam("code") String productCode, @RequestParam("name") String categoryName, Model model) {
    Customer customer = customerManager.getCustomer("Sonx", "Nkuks");

    if(customer != null) {
        Basket shopBasket = ShoppingBasketUtils.addToBasket(productCode, categoryManager.getCategory(categoryName), 
                basketManager.getBasket(customer.getReferenceNumber()), basketManager);     
        basketManager.update(shopBasket);
        model.addAttribute("basket",shopBasket);
        model.addAttribute("customer", customer.getFirstName()+" "+customer.getLastName());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", basketManager.getTotalNumberOfItems(shopBasket));
        model.addAttribute("totalPrice", ShoppingBasketUtils.currencyFormat(basketManager.getTotalProductPrice(shopBasket)));       
        return "basketItems";   
    }

    model.addAttribute("customer", "test".concat(" test"));
    return "/error";            
}
```

}

Then the form ...

```
<form:form commandName="basket">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer Name : </td>
                <td>${customer}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"
            border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Products:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td>Product Code</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Remove</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${basket.products}" var="product">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${product.name}</td>
                        <td>${product.productCode}</td>
                        <td>${product.description}</td>
                        <td>${product.price}</td>
                        <td><form:checkbox path="removeItemCodes" value="${product.productCode}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>            
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Price</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>                             
                    <td>${totalPrice}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Items</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>                     
                    <td>${totalItems}</td>
                </tr>   
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>        
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Remove Items" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>                                                    
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="../index.html"/>">Return to Home Page</a></td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Logout</a>
                    (<security:authentication property="principal.username" />)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When i press the link from the first JSP "" the controller succesfully execute the method populateBasket and loads the Form. But when i submit the form, i want it to call the POST method (basketItems)... But it doesn't, pressng the submit button always executes the GET method (populateBasket) .. This doesn't happen if i load the form directly from the index page, it loads successfully . Problem is when coming from that JSP ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to submit to a different URL from the one that was used to retrieve the page, you need to explicitly set the `action` on it.  Otherwise Spring is going to just fill it in with the current URL.